# Почем отправляються 2 Ajax-Get запроса одновременно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

При клике у меня отправляются 2 Get запроса. Вот html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Введите адрес сайта</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteTitle">
    </div>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Проверить</button>
```

И запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "check.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                URL: $("#siteTitle").val()
            },
            success: function () {
                $('#result').load("check.php");
            }
        });
    });
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это  исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый запрос: `$.ajax({ url: "check.php", ...`

Второй запрос: `$('#result').load("check.php");`

Непонятно, что Вы хотите исправить. Если ответ на `ajax` уже содержит html, который надо показать, то

```
        success: function (html) {
            $('#result').html(html);
        }
```

Comment: Поняла >< спасибо, была невнимательной